# Possible to communicate with new master without process restart?

Tags: ros, rospy, roscore, rosmaster

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Often when debugging, a launch which was responsible for the original Master goes down. When this happens things that were connected that stay up are unable to communicate with the new Master when it comes up.

- Is there a way around this?
- Is it perhaps possible to reinitialize the node so that it connects to a new Master?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11908/possible-to-communicate-with-new-master-without-process-restart?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2011-11-11

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In rospython it seems it's possible (if dangerous?) to do the following:

```
rospy.client._init_node_args = None
rospy.init_node( "node_name" )
```

I'm not sure if it's wise but it seems to work.

---

Originally posted by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2020-02-14**:
That is not a valid workaround.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I always launch a master manually with roscore for this reason.  IMO there's too much potential for weird inconsistencies, e.g., with parameter server values, to try reconnecting.

---

Originally posted by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) with karma: 1479 on 2011-11-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-11-11**:
Probably the better option, but I'm curious none-the less to know if nodes can be made to recover from losing a Master/reattach to new Master